# How to enable UITableView swipe to delete along with horizontal page swiping

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

In one of my app, I am having multiple table views inside a horizontal scroll view. So, user can horizontally swipe between table views. I am not using `UIPageViewController` for some reason.

The problem that I am facing is that I have swipe to delete feature on my `UITableView` but does not work when I have multiple pages in the horizontal scroll view.

Is there an elegant way to provide both the features at the same time?

Comment: Either add delete button on tableview or add long press gesture for deleting row(instead of having swipe gesture).

Comment: A good question ! Very much looking forward to everyone's answer!

Comment: @Abhinav, if you are the APP, how could you know the user want to delete or swipe page when he is swiping left to in UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass UIScrollView and implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate. Then return true in gestureRecognizer(_:,shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith) for the appropriate recognizers.